# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS doesn't load main window after login

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, bootloader

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my HP Pavilion laptop.

It worked properly for 10 days after I upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. But now I have a problem after typing my password in the login window. It doesn't load anything, but it shows only the background theme display picture.

The only information I can see while the system boots is:

```
dev/sda2:clean,451381/30236672 files.47752164/120944128 blocks
```

(files and blocks in this output are increasing with every boot)

I don't know what exact issue is this. This happened after installing the OS update.

The guest session works properly. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: was this condition triggered by installing graphic drivers for  Nvidia or AMD card ?      when this happens can you pull up a terminal window ( ctrl-alt-T )   ...  can you reach the console  (  ctrl-alt-F1 ) if so then doing ( ctrl-alt-F7 ) will toggle you back ...  if terminal fails and console succeeds then you can fix a bad graphics driver issue from your console window

Comment: dev/sda2:clean,451381/30236672 files.47752164/120944128 blocks                   this kind of information only i can seen while system boot

Comment: still i didn't know  what exact issue is this.but i can work on guest session,this guest session work  properly

Answer (score 0):

please check whether you have got any **icons** in **right top corner** of your desktop window. if yes, no problem in installing. Even though 16.04 OS having some drawbacks, it is very good at its performance matter